# How to rethrow caught exception in progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I can't find any information on how to rethrow the same exception that I just caught.

My catch expression looks like this:

```
CATCH ex1 AS Progress.Lang.Error :
        MESSAGE ex1:NumMessages.
        DEFINE VARIABLE iteration AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
        DO iteration = 1 TO 6:
             clsLog:inf(ex1:GetMessage(iteration)).
        END.

         clsLog:inf(SUBSTITUTE("ex1:CallStack: &1", ex1:CallStack)).
    END CATCH.
```

How do I rethrow this specific exception without loosing any of the messages or data it carries? Or if you can find anything on the Internet about rethrowing exceptions in progress I would be thankful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You re-throw just like throwing:

```
UNDO, THROW ex1 .
```